# How to reformat a USB to not be a bootable operating system

Tags: usb, disk-utility, partition, unix

I recently created a bootable USB from a .img file, here's what the USB looks like:

[image: linuxcoe]

And this is what it looks like in Disk Utility:

[image: diskutil]

Is there a way to reformat this USB to just store files?

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us what you tried to do in Disk Utility and what failed. At the very least, you should be able reformat it as Mac OS Extended (Journaled) if you want to store files on your Macintosh. Does this not work?

Answer (score 1):

If you insert the USB drive, launch Disk utility and select the USB drive on the left side of the Disk Utility window you should now be able to operate on it.

Personally I would select Partition and then the number of partitions you want. Then apply it.

That should do it

Comment: I probably should've mentioned I know nothing about this stuff, so if I wanted it to be a normal memory stick to store things normally, how many partitions would I need? @Steve Chambers
Also, I think I know what the partitions are, but can you tell me just in case?

Comment: Partitions segment a drive into pieces. If it has 4 partitions then to your Mac it will *look* like 4 different drives. For most purposes one partition is all you ever need